# Skype-bot, message to all contacts

Tags: skype-bots

What method Skype bot can get a list of his contacts?
And is there a way to send a message to all the contacts of a single POST-request? 
The documentation I describe these methods have not found https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/docs/api/chat